# How to submit a form with file upload using google drive and sheets api in node.js +express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I am currently working on a project where there is a registration form where user will put their information with a pdf or image of a receipt. On submit the reciept will be uploaded into the admin's google drive and generate a webviewlink. Then all the information of the form with the webviewlink will be stored into google sheets. How do I do that? I have researched a bit. Some uses service account or another solution is by creating credintials. I am very confused how I should approach.

I have tried google client api but having a problem with getting refresh token. I saw a video of getting refresh token from googleauthplayground but I dont think its a professional and optimal way to do that.